Validity of event notation for stochastic process & initial distribution
Let $X=(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N_0}$ be a Markov chain. We can suppose it has a finite set of states $S$ and is homogenous for simplicity, but the question should apply more generally. This naturally admits a sample path space $\Omega=S^{\mathbb N_0}$. It is generally required to specify an initial distribution $\mathcal L(X_0)$ in order to have a probability distribution on this sample path space. Often one might just use notation "$\mathbb P$" for this distribution (implicitly relying on knowing precisely $\mathcal L(X_0)$ since otherwise we simply cannot compute anything for this process).
Let $x$ be some distribution on the state space (i.e. we can have $\mathcal L(X_0)=x$), and let $n\in\mathbb N_0$ be some specified timestep and $a\in S$ some specified state.
Question: Is is coherent to write $\{\omega\in\Omega\mid X_n(\omega)=a, \mathcal L(X_0)=x\}$?
Can the notation be justified by arguing that there is a larger parent space which includes all possible initial distributions (as a valid set), and that it's ok to explicitly include the initial distribution in the probability notation this way in order to specify a particular subset of this larger space?
Now, writing $\mathbb P(X_n=a)$ is fine and of course implies we already must know what the initial distribution is, which of course tells us what "$\mathbb P$" we are using here. But is writing $\mathbb P(X_n=a \mid \mathcal L(X_0)=x)$ ever justified and coherent?
Either way, the initial distribution must be known in some way. Wouldn't it be obvious what is meant by $\mathbb P(X_n=a \mid \mathcal L(X_0)=x)$? Or would it be more preferable/correct to just say: "Let $\mathcal L(X_0)=x$, and compute $\mathbb P(X_n=a)$." Alternatively, one could write: "Compute $\mathbb P(X_n=a \mid \mathcal L(X_0)=x)$."
I am solely concerned with what is considered "correct notation" here. To my mind, both answers seem justified and simply a matter of preference. I would appreciate clear articulations of that same opinion though, in addition to arguments for other positions too. Even if this notation is generally not preferred, can it be technically correct and justified? That's what I really think the situation is here, but I could simply be wrong.
